How can I implement a static `clone` method in class in TypeScript
I want to implement a static clone method for a class and I wrote the code bellow:
type Constructor<T, S> = { new ( settings: S ): T }

class Base<Settings> {

    
    static clone<T extends Base<any>, S>( this: Constructor<T, S>, node: T ): T {
        return new this( node.settings );
    }

    settings: Settings;

    constructor( settings: Settings ) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}

class Sub<T> extends Base<T> {}

Sub.clone( new Sub( {} ) );

Here if I don't want to use any with Base<any>, what shall I do to modify the code?

Is any really the problem here? I'd say that TS is never going to infer the generic type argument the way you want. In your code above, the result of clone is Sub<unknown> and not Sub<{}>. That problem seems bigger to me, and harder to resolve. If all you care about is any (and it's not clear why), then use unknown, or even S.  But there are bigger problems here that you're not even mentioning. How should we proceed?

@jcalz Thank you very much, would you like to give me more advice?

Um... maybe you should [edit] the question to either: explain why you care about any and acknowledge that the return type is Sub<unknown> and that you're okay with it, or that at least it is not the subject of the question; or: remove the part about any and ask for how to type it so that the return type is Sub<{}> and show input output examples of what you want to see (should you be able to write Sub1.clone(new Sub2({x: 123})), and why types should they be, etc).
